# Clarifying increase of salary after certification

Tags: salary, certification

I am fairly new to the job (2 months), with the employer we just signed contract of me working for him for X amount nothing more.

Me and employer verbally came to agreement that I will need to pass certification in 3 month after starting to the job for the increase in salary. The certification can be passed by basic or advanced levels. After certified I would get an increase of salary based on the level. Basic level will increase salary by 5 units and advanced by 7 units.

**The problem:** Now that I have passed certification with advanced level, I am not sure on amount of increase, as I never thought that I could pass it with advanced. Should it be X + 5 + 7 or just X + 7, I didn't discuss this situation with employer before.

**The Question:** What would be the best way to inquire this question from employer, without sounding greedy?

Comment: If you do not ask, you wont known. No-one better than them will know their own rules. Is this a trick question?

Comment: Wanting to know how much you'll get paid doesn't make you sound greedy, although I can't quite figure out the logic that brings you to X+5+7 if they just said what you said (although if they said something like getting the certification gives 5 units and getting it on an advanced level gives 7 units **on top of that**, +12 would make sense).

Comment: @Dukeling yes, my main problem is that I didn't clarify it at that time, so interpretation can be different, given next time will clarify such things beforehand. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems simple to me.

Your salary will increase by 7 units because you passed the advanced certification.  Otherwise, you would have been told that the advanced certification would earn you 12 units more.

Just assume this will be the case.

Comment: thanks, I do assume it as such. However I believe it will be better to clarify it with employer first, do you have an advice on how to approach my employer?

Comment: @Hatik from your wording its also fairly clear to me that advanced certification is a +7 units and not to be meant accumulative to the +5. It would look bad in my books if you went to ask for more assuming somehow you would get  both.

Answer (score 2):

Since your wording does **not** indicate "an additional 7 units" for the advanced certification, I would assume the total amount is 7 units.

If you want to confirm while leaving the possibility open for your employer to indicate 12 units, I would contact to the department responsible for payroll.

I would ask them to verify whether the certification is reflected in your file, when the change in pay will take effect, and what the change in pay will be.

This approach has the fringe benefit of alerting you if anything is amiss. If your boss forgot to file paperwork or if the salary isn't changed on time, as examples, you will know that corrective action is necessary.